Is the distribution of an odd function symmetric?
An odd function is defined as, f(x) = -f(-x), which suggests that it has same distribution for positive and negative values. In other words, it seems that the distribution p_f(y) = p_f(-y).
This seems reasonable to me, but I haven't been able to find a theorem or proof to support it. Does anyone know more about this? (Can you refer theorem or proof about this?)
Thank you.
